# How to pass command line arguments to web debug session in VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I need to pass parameter to debug session in VS Code while programming in flutter/dart. I added the following data into `launch.json` as described in [documentation](https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/).

```
{
  "configurations": {
    ..
    // Any custom environment variables to set when running the app with this
    // launch config.
    "env": {
      "DEBUG_MODE": true
    }

    // Arguments to be passed to the Dart or Flutter app.
    "args": [
        "--dart-define", 
        "DEBUG_VALUE=true",
    ],  
}
```

and tried to read the value so:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final debugMode = String.fromEnvironment('DEBUG_MODE');
  final debugValue = String.fromEnvironment('DEBUG_VALUE');
  ...
}
```

but variables are empty, and `args` list is also empty. So please give me advise what I did wrong?

Comment: @pskink `but variables are empty, and args list is also empty.`

Comment: btw the link you posted is saying about "toolArgs", not "args": `"configurations": [
{
"name": "Flutter",
"request": "launch",
"type": "dart",
"toolArgs": [
"--dart-define",
"MY_VAR=MY_VALUE",
"--dart-define", "MY_OTHER_VAR=MY_OTHER_VALUE"
]
}
]`

Comment: https://dartcode.org/docs/launch-configuration/

Comment: use `final debugMode = const String.fromEnvironment('DEBUG_MODE');`

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help.

Comment: it worked for: vcsode ver `1.60.0`, flutter ver `2.7.0-3.0.pre` - i used either `args` or `toolArgs` and it worked in both cases (btw also two variants work: `["--dart-define", "MY_VAR=MY_VALUE"]` and `"[--dart-define=MY_VAR=MY_VALUE"]`)

Answer (score 8):

Are you definitely using `const` when reading the value? For reasons I don't entirely understand, this seems to only work if the value is `const`:

With this in my launch.json:

```
"toolArgs": [
    "--dart-define",
    "FOO=bar",
]
```

And code like:

```
final foo1 = String.fromEnvironment('FOO');
final foo2 = const String.fromEnvironment('FOO');
print('FOO: "$foo1" "$foo2"');
```

The output is

```
flutter: FOO: "" "bar"
```

So if String.fromEnvironment is called in a non-const context, it doesn't seem to return the value.

Edit: Actually, in web, not using `const` results in an exception. But with `const`, it still works as expected.

Comment: Its wired I think,does anyone have some explanations why with const this worked?

Comment: @zex_rectooor there's an open issue with some more details about it at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870

Answer (score 1):

Correct version is

```
{
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev",
                "--dart-define",
                "app.flavor=dev",
            ],
            "flutterMode": "debug"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter (profile)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev",
                "--dart-define",
                "app.flavor=dev",
            ],
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter (release)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev",
                "--dart-define",
                "app.flavor=dev",
            ],
            "flutterMode": "release"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter (dev)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev",
                "--dart-define",
                "app.flavor=dev",
            ],
            "flutterMode": "debug"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter (dev profile)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev",
                "--dart-define",
                "app.flavor=dev",
            ],
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter (dev release)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev",
                "--dart-define",
                "app.flavor=dev",
            ],
            "flutterMode": "release"
        },
        
    ]
}
```